# Как отправить одним сообщением в ответ пользователю через bot.send_message

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Через телеграмм бот обращаюсь на БД  с товарами. Но в ответ пользователь получает поочередно список товаров. Хотелось одним сообщение отправить весь список.

Отрывок из кода:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(c, show_category)  
def show_category (message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_data=message.text

    cursor.execute(f'''
        select product_id, title, price from products 
        join categories using(category_id) where category_name=%s
    ''', (user_data,))

    category_products=cursor.fetchall()

    for products in category_products:
        product_id=products[0]
        title=products[1]
        price=products[2]

        message_to_user = f'''{title}\nЦена: {price}\nПодробнее: /product_{product_id}'''

        bot.send_message(chat_id, message_to_user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всмысле как? До итерации (for) определяете `message_to_user = ""`, в самом итераторе меняете на

```
message_to_user += f'{title}\nЦена: {price}\nПодробнее: /product_{product_id}\n'
```

И уже после и главное ВНЕ итератора, делаете сенд месседж.
В итоге что-то вроде этого.

```
message_to_user = ""
for products in category_products:
    product_id=products[0]
    title=products[1]
    price=products[2]

    message_to_user += f'{title}\nЦена: {price}\nПодробнее: /product_{product_id}\n'

bot.send_message(chat_id, message_to_user)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает :-)